# Override partials and templates from backend sysext

Tags: fluid, typo3-7.6.x

Is it possible to override a partial or template from the sysext backend extension like from other extension?
For example override the `typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Private/Partials/LoginNews.html` partial?

I something like this possible?

```
plugin.tx_backend {
  view {
    partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/backend/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible like that. The only way would be to [XCLASS](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html) the controller and change the assigned template.